# GAE datastore query not returning anything - help! error says 'query' object has no attribute (which should not be the case)

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Anyone know why my db query for h1 is pooping out?  - this is the error I'm getting:
THANK YOU ANYONE for any help - I have been looking at this for a while and can't figure it out....!!!

File "/Users/minasong/Dropbox/TS Code/main.py", line 720, in get
    logging.info("here is the type able instance %s ", type_info.headingtype_name)
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'headingtype_name'

class AdminHeading_Edit_Type(Handler):
    def get(self,type_name):

```
    category_level = "ONE"

    type_info = HeadingType_Table.all().filter("__key__ =", type_name)
    h1 = Level_1_Headings.all().filter("heading_type =", type_info)


    logging.info("here is the type able instance %s ", type_info.headingtype_name)

    self.render('new_entries/ADMIN_Heading_1Edit_2List.html', ones=h1, heading_type=type_name, category_level=category_level, type_into=type_info)
```

And here's my datastore entity definition: 
    class HeadingType_Table(db.Model):
    headingtype_name = db.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    type_description = db.TextProperty()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hard to tell from your sample, but I suspect your problem is this;

```
type_info = HeadingType_Table.all().filter("__key__ =", type_name)
```

...sets type_info to a `Query` object containing *all matching "headingtypes"*.

logging.info("...", type_info.headingtype_name)

...tries to log property `headingtype_name` from the `Query` object. I suspect you mean to do that on a `Model` object.

Either use `get()` instead of `all()` to get a single `Model` object, or iterate over the result to log `headingtype_name` of each `Model` object returned from the `Query` individually.

Comment: thanks for your input - just did a get_by_key_name and it worked